# Insert enumerate items inside a theorem environment, in LyX

Tags: lyx, theorems, amsthm

I want to create the following code in LyX:

```
\begin{exercise}
Prove that blah blah, and show that:
 \begin{enumerate}
   \item first item
   \item some second item
 \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

I load the Theorems (AMS) Module (shipped with LyX installation) and when I type it in the editor, I rather get as a LaTeX code the following:

```
\begin{xca}
Prove that blah blah, and show that:
\end{xca}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item
\item some second item
\end{enumerate}
```

That is, inserting enumerate automatically exists from the `xca` environment. How to fix this, if possible at all?

I prefer not to use the Insert TeX code interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

Press Enter to create a new line, then Tab to enter into Depth: 1:

[image]

Then change the new environment to enumerate, or itemize.

[image]

Press three times the Return key to exit from the Exercise environment into the Standard one.